# Почему зовут символ @ "собака"? Why is the @-symbol called "dog"?

Tags: лексикон

Почему зовут символ @ "собака"?  Why is the @-symbol called "dog"?

I saw this translation on the Babbel website. Most of the Russian terms regarding computer technology seem to be either direct loanwords or calques from English, but I have absolutely no insight regarding why @ would be called "собака".

Is there a historical reason for this perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Одна из версий происхождения названия «собака»: на алфавитно-цифровых
>   мониторах персональных компьютеров серии ДВК (1980-е годы) «хвостик»
>   рисуемого на экране изображения этого символа был очень коротким,
>   что придавало ему сходство со схематически нарисованной собачкой.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/@

Забавно, что, например, в датском этот символ называется snabel a. Snabel – большой нос или хобот.

Comment: шнобель то бишь)))

Comment: I don't believe in the wiki's version. It became a part of colloquial language only in mid-90's, so unlikely it's an older geek term. In my  imagination, it is related to the exclamation "собака" in a situation of frustration - with a strange symbol inserted between Latin letters. For many Russian PC users the labour of reading English words is challenging enough. And here they see something invented to mock at them: вот сс... (сука) собака! So that (how I've just read it) will be the name for it from now on :)

Comment: Nevertheless it is an old geek term :)

Comment: В  те далёкие времена @ называлось "ухо", потому что оно действительно на него похоже.

Comment: Я в середине 80-х слышал название "кукиш".  А официально он назывался "коммерческое а".

Comment: не только по-датски, но и по-шведски. А по-норвежски говорят alfakrøll, что можноперебести как "альфа-завитушка".